# regex to remove round brackets from a string

Tags: java, regex

i have a string

```
String s="[[Identity (philosophy)|unique identity]]";
```

i need to parse it to .

```
s1 = Identity_philosphy 
s2= unique identity
```

I have tried following code

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\[\\[)(\\w*?\\s\\(\\w*?\\))(\\s*[|])\\w*(\\]\\])");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while(m.find())
{
....
}
```

But the pattern is not matching..

Please Help

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to insert the underscore character where there used to be brackets?  If so, what is the specific rule for doing this?

Comment: Have you tried using something like this to help you?
[RegExr](http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/) Using that website I was able to create a pattern which will match exactly what you want. This will work on that website: `(\[\[)|(\()|(\))|(\|)|(\]\])` Insert double backslashes for it to work within Java: `(\\[\\[)|(\\()|(\\))|(\\|)|(\\]\\])`

Comment: Did [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59933770/3832970) help?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
String s="[[Identity (philosophy)|unique identity]]";
String[] results = s.replaceAll("^\\Q[[\\E|]]$", "")    // Delete double brackets at start/end
      .replaceAll("\\s+\\(([^()]*)\\)","_$1")           // Replace spaces and parens with _
       .split("\\Q|\\E");                               // Split with pipe
System.out.println(results[0]);
System.out.println(results[1]);
```

Output:

```
Identity_philosophy
unique identity
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
String s="[[Identity (philosophy)|unique identity]]";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\[{2}(.*)\\|(.*)]]").matcher(s);
if (m.matches()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1).replaceAll("\\W+", " ").trim().replace(" ", "_")); // // => Identity_philosphy
    System.out.println(m.group(2).trim()); // => unique identity
}
```

See a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/XPFvg8).

**Details**

The  `"\\[{2}(.*)\\|(.*)]]"` with `matches()` is parsed as a `^\[{2}(.*)\|(.*)]]\z` pattern that matches a string that starts with `[[`, then matches and captures any 0 or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible into Group 1, then matches a `|`, then matches and capture any 0 or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible into Group 2 and then matches `]]`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eHiL1l/1).

The contents in Group 2 can be trimmed from whitespace and used as is, but Group 1 should be preprocessed by replacing all 1+ non-word character chhunks with a space (`.replaceAll("\\W+", " ")`), then trimming the result (`.trim()`) and replacing all spaces with `_` (`.replace(" ", "_")`) as the final touch.